# Razor Page IFormFile .Net 5.0 attachment Header Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, .net-core, upload, iformfile

I'm using .Net 5.0 (Razor Pages) and IFormFile to upload user image, in ASP.NET I used to validate the header of the files to make sure that the uploaded files are valid for example not to change an EXE file extension to Jpg and upload it so any help to validate the headers of the IFormFile?

Function Used in ASP.NET: and I need to implement in Razor Pages

```
public string validateFileToUpload(FileUpload objFile)
    {
        string errorMessageToReturn = string.Empty;
        // DICTIONARY OF ALL IMAGE FILE HEADER
        Dictionary<string, byte[]> imageHeader = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
        imageHeader.Add("JPG", new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0 });
        imageHeader.Add("JPEG", new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0 });

        imageHeader.Add("PDF", new byte[] { 0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46 });
        imageHeader.Add("DOCX", new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x03, 0x04 });
        imageHeader.Add("DOC", new byte[] { 0xD0, 0xCF, 0x11, 0xE0 });
        imageHeader.Add("MSG", new byte[] { 0xD0, 0xCF, 0x11, 0xE0, 0xA1, 0xB1, 0x1A, 0xE1 });

        byte[] header;

       
        string fileExt;
        fileExt = objFile.FileName.Substring(objFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToUpper();

       
        byte[] tmp;
        try
        {
            tmp = imageHeader[fileExt];
            header = new byte[tmp.Length];
        }
        catc
        {
            errorMessageToReturn = "Invalid File.";
            return errorMessageToReturn;
        }
        

        
        objFile.FileContent.Read(header, 0, header.Length);

        if (CompareArray(tmp, header))
        {
            errorMessageToReturn = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessageToReturn = "Invalid ." + fileExt + " file.";
            
        }

        return errorMessageToReturn;
    }

    private bool CompareArray(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
    {
        if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a1[i] != a2[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Allam,what about validating the file extension?

Comment: i need a function to validate the file headers along with the file extension

Comment: Hi @Allam,Which header you want to validate?Do you mean `Content-Type=multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Dear Rena, Thank you for your reply, below is the function i used to call when validating a file in asp.net, i need to implement the same function in Razor pages but the iFormFile doesnt return the header file

Answer (score 0):

Was solved using the below instead of  objFile.FileContent.Read(header, 0, header.Length);

```
if (objFile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    objFile.CopyTo(ms);
                    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < header.Length; i++)
                {
                    header[i] = fileBytes[i];
                }
                
                }
            }
```